# javascript click a button with if statement to compare text variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, button

can you please help me with this :

I am trying to click three different buttons with different ids, but based on a string variable name in javascript like :

```
function my_custom_js_func(){

  jQuery( "#listViewer" ).click();

};
```

but this will always click the button with id listViewer

i have a variable :

```
 var viewTog = "List";
```

or :
      var viewTog = "Grid";

I want to do something like this :

```
 function my_custom_js_func(){

  if (viewTog == "List") {jQuery( "#listViewer" ).click();};
  if (viewTog == "Grid") {jQuery( "#gridViewer" ).click();};

};
```

but it doesn't work, I am using the variable viewTog as a memory.

thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your names are consistent as you show, you can just convert the variable to lower case and concatenate it to `Viewer`.

```
jQuery("#" + viewTog.toLowerCase() + "Viewer").click();
```

Or just normalize the case in the variable so that you don't need to convert to lower case each time.

Comment: thank you for the reply, it sounds great but still doesn't work with me, how can I wrap it in a function. it should be like this  :  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( document ).on( 'js_event_wpv_pagination_completed', function() {
      my_custom_js_func();
    });
    $( document ).on( 'js_event_wpv_parametric_search_results_updated', function() {
      my_custom_js_func();
    }); 
    function my_custom_js_func(){
      //$('input').on('change', function() {})
    jQuery("#" + viewTog + "Viewer").click();
    };
});

Comment: Thank you 100 times, I solved it using your code, the issue was my variable was not global !